# Write Permissions Denied when using sshfs to Mount Remote Directory on Boot

Tags: ssh, centos7, fstab, sshfs, fuse

I have two Cent OS 7 servers I am trying to mount a directory from my host server to my client server. I want this to automatically mount on boot.

On my host machine (hostmachine.local) I setup a user and gave that user sudo privileges.

On my client machine I setup an ssh key and associated it with the sudo user I created on my host machine. I then added the following to my `/etc/fstab` file...

```
sshfs#sudouser@hostmachine.local:/var/www/vhosts /mnt/hostdir   fuse    _netdev,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other 0 0
```

When I reboot the machine it mounts and I can read the contents of the `/var/www/vhosts` directory from the client (via `/mnt/hostdir`), but when I try and write to the mounted directory I get a permission denied error.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you wouldn't just use NFS for this?